# Unable to download file using ionic file transfer plugin in ionic 5+

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

here im using ionic file transfer plugin for downloading a file and when ever i tried to download the file im getting below error

[image: 401]

and also every time i build a file i need to add the below code in android also

```
public class FileProvider extends androidx.core.content.FileProvider
```

is there any other alternative for this download . i checked capacitor site but im not sure how to use file storage plugin in that  and below is my code using file transfer

```
 pdfUrl = 'https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/NatureDeepReview.pdf';


  constructor(private transfer: FileTransfer, private file: File) {}

  download() {
    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
    const url = this.pdfUrl;
  fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory).then((entry) => {
    console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
    this.saveData = entry.toURL();

  }, (error) => {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android, `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` requires `cordova-plugin-whitelist`.

Install it with `npm install cordova-plugin-whitelist` and then run `npx cap update`

Also, `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` requires the path to the file where you want to write, you passed a directory, you should change `fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory)` to `fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + '/NatureDeepReview.pdf')`

Answer (score 1):

try to the following :

firstly add the plugin:  `cordova-plugin-whitelist`

secondely in the config.xml add the following `<access origin="*" />`

and the reference is used to answer the issue is  :
https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1199

Answer (score 1):

Check permission in your android manifest file and try again if your manifest file ok you added your permission then you have to check your destination route.

in your android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30330229)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create a [whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) - download the plugin via NPM

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

And add the following to config.xml

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```